# MySQL Query - Check if data row contains a user_id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `sessions` table and what I am trying to do is run a query to check if a certain account is logged in.

[image]

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE data LIKE '%4%'
```

But with a query like that, if the user_id of "14" is logged in, that query will return True.  How do I check to see if a certain number exists and matches exactly?

Comment: `matches exactly` isn't that what the `=` sign is for? `SELECT id FROM sessions WHERE data = 'something'`

Comment: @JimmyPena I get it now, there's a `data` column with (gasp) more than one bit of information in it!

Comment: your database structure is bad, you shouldn't store multiple attributes/values in one column [wiki Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @Puggan Se: Session tables normally have their own serialization / abstraction layers on top. What we see above is the standard for DB based session storage. However, I agree depending on the situation that another field could be added if DB (not session) queries are going to be enacted on it. see my answer for an example of when/why to add a field and break the standard form for session tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the delimiters in your search:

```
WHERE data LIKE '%:4;%'
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add another field for user_id to the session table?

EXAMPLE:
I have a site where a user can only be logged in from one location at a time. If they try and log in from another location (IE start a new session) then i kill all of their previous logins.

So as part of my login script:

```
// log this user out of any other active sessions
$sql = sprintf("DELETE 
    FROM sessions 
    WHERE id_user=%s", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id_user'])
);

// Associate this session with this user
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE sessions 
    SET id_user=%s 
    WHERE id=%s", 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['id_user']), 
    session_id()
);
```

and so i can have id_user as an additional field in my session FKed to my user table... its a little more normalized and lets you do quick "Who is currently using this site" queries without too much parsing and fuss.